# ArangoDB java-driver reuse of objects

Tags: java, arangodb, object-reference

In many of the examples using the java arangoDB [driver](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver), they use method chaining

```
arangoDB.db("myDatabase").createCollection("myCollection", null);
```

or

```
arangoDB.db("myDatabase").collection("myCollection").insertDocument(myObject);
```

Are there any drawbacks with re-using objects?

```
ArangoDatabase db = arangoDB.db("myDatabase");
...
db.createCollection("myCollection", null);
ArangoCollection coll = db.collection("myCollection");
...
coll.insertDocument(myObject);
```

I am not sure if chaining approach is preferred or just for simplicity (fewer lines for an example).

- Is there much of a performance benefit to reuse? Less object creation overhead...
- Are connection, database and collection objects thread safe? i.e
  after getting a database can the object be shared between multiple
  threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse instances of ArangoDatabase, ArangoCollection, ArangoGraph, ArangoVertexCollection, ArangoEdgeCollection.

- Yes, there is a small performance benefit through less object creation.
- Yes, all of them are thread-safe. You can share them between threads.